# What is the best way to store an admin API token in Next.js ? Feel like storing it client side as http only cookie is risky

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sylius

I'm working on a e-commerce using next.js and sylius API and the API admin routes are secured using JWT. So in order to fetch products (for example), i need to login to the API, get the token and then fetch the products using the token. The most common method to be able to send the token on every new requests to the API is to store it in a HTTP-only cookie.

As the pages are generated statically, i feel i don't need (and want) to expose the API token to the client. So i'm wondering the best way to store the token ?

Here the different options i have in mind right now:

- store the token as a http only cookie and use it server side (with a proxy using next js API pages) in order to call the sylius API. Like i said, i'm not confortable to store the API token into the client, it seems risky to me, as it will be exposed to everyone, and with that token you can access the admin API.
- configure the API in order to prevent the token from expiring, and store it in the next js app as an environnement variable (.env.local), so that it's not exposed to the client and can be used for fetching the api when generating static pages. The official ecommerce theme of Next.Js seems to use that method (https://github.com/vercel/commerce/blob/f770ad7a91059a2ecfbb9de1bac111dfe7016124/framework/bigcommerce/api/index.ts#L82)
- store the token somewhere in the next js structure but not as an environnement variable (maybe a config file?), so that it can be replaced if necessary (if the token expires etc).
- get the token and store it in the react state as is it will be used once only for generating all static pages. On each build the token will be asked again by the API and then used for fetching the API for exporting the static pages with the content. It don't need to be saved more time than the building step.

For me the last option seems better but i feel i'm missing something there, i'm kinda new to next, so i'm not sure exactly if its a good solution.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I get a great answer from a reddit user ("supermaguireray"), so i post it as an answer here:

"First of all, in any session management mechanism the correct information needs to live on the correct domains, what I mean is that your client can only have access to a identification information, but never to data used in the server, these can be applied to a server-side session, when a ID for the user data stored on the server is sent to the client (preferably encrypted), or in a JWT where a encrypted string is sent to the client (identification), and decrypted on the server (Data).

With that said, the only reason you should send the API token to the client is if you need to fetch data directly from a browser. Storing as a httpOnly cookie is the most secure way.

In case you only need the cookie fetch data to the next backend, to render your SSG or ISR pages, there is no need to send a cookie to the client. Just store the token in your server. I would store it as env variable. Use next.config.js->runtime-configuration.

Or, you can keep a expiration date for the token, and store the credentials, maybe even in a DynamoDB or FaunaDB app."